# Drupal 7: How do I retrieve a node's Content Type from within a component's prepocess function?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I've got a component that requires me to get the content type of the node the component appears on. I saw there exists a function to get that for me:

```
node_type_get_name($node)
```

However, when I use this function within the components pre-process hook, eg:

```
 my_component_preprocess_my_component_theme(&$variables, $node) {
   dpm(node_type_get_name($node));
 }
```

I get nothing.

If I `dpm($node);` I get the title of the component, not the node.

Would anyone know how I can retrieve the node's content-type?

Comment: what component ? and your theme/module name is my_component ?

Comment: menu_get_item() works too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load current node like this:

```
<?php
$node = menu_get_object();
if ( !empty($node) ) {
  print "Have node";
}
?>
```

So, you'll have full node loaded and can check it's type (`$node->type`) and anything else you need.

https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2010-07-28/how-to-get-node-object-or-nid-for-the-current-page

And if you don't have the node it means, of course, current page is not a node (maybe a view or some custom page...).